# Facebook fanpage : how to reach German and American targets

Tags: site-growth, facebook

I'm the admin of a facebook fan page named "**Eventi Culturali Napoli**", I would like to see some visitors from abroad, especially Germany and the USA, what can I do for now without doing paid advertising campaigns?

I would like to start getting some visitors and share from abroad, to give my free service not only to local visitors.

Comment: +1 and welcome to our community! However, do you not know anyone in Germany or America? Knowing people in those locations would be the most sensible way to grow the population of users from those places right?